# Django Autocomplete Light limiting query results

Tags: python, django, django-autocomplete-light

When I register autocomplete_light.AutocompleteModelBase and use it in my form, the results that are shown are always limited to 20. I can't find any option in the docs to increase the number of results that gets displayed on the form.

autocomplete_light_regisrty.py

```
class IssueAutocomplete(autocomplete_light.AutocompleteModelBase):
    model = Issue
    search_fields = ('^issue_number',)

autocomplete_light.register(
    IssueAutocomplete,
    attrs={
        'placeholder': 'Type an issue number...',
        'data-autocomplete-minimum-characters': 1
    },
)
```

forms.py

```
class StoryForm(autocomplete_light.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Story
        fields = ('slug', 'summary', 'author', 'editor', 'issue',)
```

But when I search my form, only a maximum of 20 results appear, even though I have well over 60. This is replicated when I go to /autocomplete/IssueAutocomplete. Only 20 results appear at a time.

How do I get a full list of resuls?

Comment: [limit_choices](http://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html?highlight=limit#autocomplete_light.autocomplete.model.AutocompleteModel.limit_choices) ?

Comment: You are correct. It used to be limit_results. Thanks you.

Comment: Ok, I post it as answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should to use [limit_choices](http://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html?highlight=limit#autocomplete_light.autocomplete.model.AutocompleteModel.limit_choices) as is described in documentation.

Answer (score 4):

By default `AutocompleteModelBase` has the attribute named limit_choices which by default is set tot 20. You can overwrite it with a new value to expand it. Although not documented, if you want *no* limit pass -1 as t[he attribute is only to slice the results](https://github.com/yourlabs/django-autocomplete-light/blob/master/autocomplete_light/autocomplete/model.py#L127)

Comment: I accepted danihp answer because he commented first. But thank you for the addition of -1, that will be useful in the future.

Comment: yea! nice link to source code ;) Also appreciated by me.